# Is it possible to add margin between parent divs depending on child class with pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple `<div>` wrapping some children which have a `class`. But the problem is that the parent `<div>` doesn't have a `class` or `id`. Is it possible to add a `margin-bottom` between the wrapping parent divs which has a specific **child** with just pure **CSS** or do I need to use **jQuery** or **JS** to achieve this?

Example of how the **HTML** could look like:

```
// parent 
    <div> 
    // children
       <h2 class="child-class-1" ></h2>     
       <p class="child-class-2" ></p>
    </div>
    
    // margin-bottom between the wrapping parent divs
    
    <div>
       <h2 class="child-class-1" ></h2>    
       <p class="child-class-2" ></p>
    </div>
```

I found an solution with pure **CSS**.

**Solution here:**

```css
div > .child-class-1, .child-class-2 {
margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
   <div style="background-color:red; height: 400px; width:400px;"> 
       <h2 class="child-class-1" ></h2>     
       <p class="child-class-2" ></p>
    </div>
    
    <div style="background-color:red; height: 400px; width:400px;">
       <h2 class="child-class-1" ></h2>    
       <p class="child-class-2" ></p>
    </div>
    
        <div style="background-color:red; height: 400px; width:400px;">
       <h2></h2>    
           <p>Dosent affect the div which dosen't have the child class</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: See [Is there a CSS parent selector?](/q/1014861/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a properties for the `<div>` tag in your HTML with external/internal style, but it's affect all the  tag in your current / all html pages

example for your css code :

```
div {
  margin-bottom: 12px
}
```

or maybe you can add custom style for just one `<div>` only with inline style, you can use :

```
<div style="margin-bottom:12px">
     <h2 class="child-class-1" ></h2>    
     <p class="child-class-2" ></p>
</div>
```

but it quite bother, since you have another `<div>` in your HTML